# Adding ec2-user to docker group

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-devops

I want to install docker on my ec2 instance.

> sudo yum install docker -y

I came to know that this command automatically creates a group 'docker'
which has root privileges by default.so I add my ec2-user to this group to execute commands without 'sudo'.

> sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user

Now this means ec2-user has root privileges
But if I want to start the docker service,why should I use

> sudo systemctl start docker

instead of simply

> systemctl start docker

Above command is giving me an error:

*Failed to start docker.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status docker.service' for details*.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because docker is system service so you must use sudo or run it without sudo as root user
or you can use

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

and after every reboot docker service will be running automatically

Comment: you mean by adding ec2 user to docker group,it only allows you to execute only docker commands without sudo but for regular commands we should use sudo ?

Comment: yes, not sure what regular commands do you mind but docker logs ps exec ... will work under ec2 without sudo